# What's the difference between Carvel `App CR` create/delete VS `kapp deploy/delete app`

Tags: kubernetes

I need to understand what's the difference between deleting an `App CR` vs `kapp delete -a <app>`. Because I see former waits for reconciliation to finish before processing `delete App CR` request.

Scenario details:

- `Kubernetes` cluster
- Deploy `kapp-controller`
- Create an `App CR` in which some resources never reconcile. Ex. if a pod is failing due to the `readiness probe`
- App status will be in the `Reconciling` state for `15m`(default deploy wait timeout)
- Right after `deploy`, fire `kubectl delete app <app-name>`, this will hang for `15m` before executing `delete request`

However, if `kapp delete -a <app_name>` is fired right after `deploy`, this runs immediately.